# What is wrong with this template in Django?

Tags: python, django

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse            #http response sends back html/basic webpage
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.template import loader
from .models import Album

# Create your views here.
'''def index(request):
    all_objects = Album.objects.all()
    html = ''
    for album in all_objects:
        url = "/music/" + str(album.id) + "/"
        html += '<a href = "' + url + '">' + album.album_title + '</a><br>'
    return HttpResponse(html)
'''
def index(request):
    all_albums = Album.objects.all()
    #template = loader.get_template('music/index.html')
    context = {'all_albums': all_albums}
    return render(request, 'music/index.html', context)
    #return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def detail(request, album_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Details of Album with id:" + str(album_id)+ "</h2>")
```

yields perfectly right templates.
And when I add the templates for an album that does not exist.
That is I have added 2 albums and synchronized with my database, and when I surf to the third template page, I should get the 404 error.
And the code for this is-

```
    from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from .models import Album


def index(request):
    all_albums = Album.objects.all()
    #template = loader.get_template('music/index.html')
    context = {'all_albums': all_albums}
    return render(request, 'music/index.html', context)
    #return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
    #render has an inbuilt http return type

def detail(request, album_id):
    try:
        album = Album.objects.get(pk=album_id)
    except Album.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Album does not exist")
    return render(request, 'music/detail.html', {'album':album})
```

When i enter http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/3/ it yields a 404 error which i wanted to do but when i type in http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/2/ it starts giving a  "TemplateDoesNotExist at /music/2/" error.
Why is this happening...

Comment: You seem to be confused about what is a template and what is a view here. Your original code works because you don't use a template in the detail view. Your second code refers to a detail.html template, which presumably doesn't exist.

Comment: no, i have added a detail.html template alongside with the index.html...

Comment: it consists of {{ album }}

Comment: can you share the directory of `detail.html`?

Comment: music/templates/music/details.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your template file `details.html` should be `detail.html`, no `s` after `detail`, as in your `views.py`, it is mentioned as `music/detail.html`.

or

you can change to `music/details.html` in your `views.py`.

The template name should be matched.

Comment: @shery224 Cool, glad it works for you, and enjoy the journey in the community, good luck :)